# Angular Response data

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have one server file ../abc.js which contains data like this:

```
var abc=[
   {
       "a":"b",
       "c":"d"
   },

   {
       "e":"f",
       "g":"h"
   }
]
```

i.e. a variable holding Array of objects.

Using angular(v4.x) Ajax call i can get the response as the whole file content but i can't make json() out of it because of this syntax.

My intention is to get the result from my service like:

```
[{
 "a":"b",
 "c": "d" 
},
{
  "e":"f",
  "g":"h"
}]
```

And my service looks like this:

```
getFileData():Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get("../abc.js")
                .map((response:Response)=>{
                     return response.json();  //Here its giving error "unexpected token v" which is coming from var keyword
     })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> //Here its giving error "unexpected token v" which is coming from var
>   keyword

You can strip of characters before `[` by using `substring` and then convert to *json*

```
return response.substring( response.indexOf("[") ).json();
```